# Как найти, в каких представлениях используются конкретные таблицы?

Tags: sql, база-данных, oracle, sqldeveloper

Добрый день.

Есть оракловая база и в ней достаточно большое количество представлений (view). Как можно быстро узнать, в каких из них есть обращения к конкретной таблице?

Смысл в том, что я хочу знать, какие представления окажутся затронуты, если я изменю таблицу.

Если нет решения средствами самой СУБД, то буду благодарен и за решение средствами среды разработки Oracle SQL Developer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Все зависимости любого объекта Oracle можно посмотреть в системном представлении `user_dependencies`. Обратите внимание, внутри view могут быть использованы обращения не только к таблицам, но и к другим представлениям, функциям и т.п. поэтому для надежности стоит рассматривать все зависимости рекурсивно:

```
 select * from user_dependencies
  start with referenced_name ='ИМЯ-ТАБЛИЦЫ'
connect by trim(referenced_name)=prior trim(name);
```

При желании добавьте условие `type='VIEW'` что бы получить информацию именно о представлениях, а не о всех объектах, зависимых от таблицы.

Comment: Спасибо большое!